# backward and forward option between different notebooks

Tags: notebooks

When I was searching about `fitting` process, this video has attracted my attention:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KolZZm8If9Q

In this video, as I show by an image, there is a possibility in which we can go to different notebooks with a forward and backward symbols. As I highlighted in the image. I have tried to find and apply this option in my Mathematica notebooks but I could not find that. How can we apply this option?

[image]

Comment: looks like an old slideshow toolbar. you can go to Format/ScreenEnvironment/Slideshow to change it.

Comment: I think firstly we have to create slide show in File/New/Slideshow. After creating and for representation we must go to  Format/ScreenEnvironment/Slideshow